# A question about the proof of Godel's Incompleteness Theorem

Tags: logic, computability, incompleteness

The article *A Computability Proof of Gödel’s First Incompleteness Theorem*, by Jørgen Veisdal on [Cantor's Paradise](https://medium.com/cantors-paradise/a-computability-proof-of-g%C3%B6dels-first-incompleteness-theorem-2d685899117c) contains the following passage:

> The second property regards the complement of a set $E$, that is, all the strings which are not in set $E$. First, notice that if $E$ is decidable, so is the complement of $E$ (we can construct a set $F$ of all the strings that are shown to not belong to $E$). As such, if the set $E$ can be constructed by a mechanical process (is computably enumerable), so too must its complement.

If a set $E$ is enumerable, why does its complement also have to be enumerable? What if its complement is infinite? Moreover, if a set $E$ is decidable, why does its complement have to be decidable?

Comment: Recursively enumerable and decidable are **not** the same.

Comment: It is a basic result of [Computability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set#Properties) that : A set A is a recursive (i.e. *decidable*) set if and only if A and the complement of A are both recursively enumerable sets.

Comment: The text above says: if E is **decidable** (and thus "computably" enumerable) also its complement is decidable. IF $E$ is decidable, both $E$ and its complement $E^c$ are enumerable. But then, we have that $E^c$ and $(E^c)^c=E$ are both enumerable; thus, also $E^c$ is decidable.

Comment: Instead of posting screenshots of text, please take the time to type out the quote you're asking about, and provide a reference to the source you're reading. This time, I tracked down the article and replaced the image with text for you.

Comment: @AlexKruckman- Thanks for typing the text. I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Decidable means there's a decision procedure for determining whether an element is in the set or not. By symmetry, this holds for the complement too: we can determine whether the element is *not* in the set or not.

However, it is **false** that the complement of a computably enumerable set is computably enumerable. In fact, this fact is very important to Gödel's theorem: one example of such a set is the set of all Gödel numbers of theorems. (Another famous one is the halting set.)

If a set $S$ is computably enumerable and so is its complement, then it is decidable, since we can decide if $x$ is in $X$ by enumerating both $S$ and it complement and seeing which list $x$ appears in. The converse is clearly true as well, so one characterization of decidable sets is those that are c.e. and whose complements are also c.e.

Comment: Ah I see. I thought that the complement being decidable meant that we could see if the complement of a string was in a set or not.